# No sound except with Flash Player in Firefox. Sound App only shows "Dummy Output"

Tags: sound, output

Using a Dell 8400 with an AC97 type soundcard. Ubuntu 12.04 (3.2.0-32-generic-pae) Everything is updated.

I only get audio through my soundcard when using Adobe Flash Player for Firefox. Nothing else works, Rhythmbox, MoviePlayer, VLCplayer, etc. These had worked prior.

In my dash the "Sound" app only shows "Dummy Output" as the only output and the recorder shows nothing for input choice. Did show other choices prior.

The systeminfo shows the driver for the sound card.

I believe problem began when I installed Flash Player through Ubuntu Software Center, but not sure.

Don't know where to go from here. Any suggested terminal commands or fixes.

Thanks.